# I am passing the correct tokenId to verifier but it is giving the null as output?

Tags: java

```
HttpTransport transport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(transport, jsonFactory )
        .setAudience(Arrays.asList("Client_ID"))  
        .setIssuer("https://accounts.google.com")
        .build();

        GoogleIdToken idToken = verifier.verify(tokenId);
        logger.info("ID token:"+idToken);
        if (idToken != null) {
          Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();

          // Print user identifier
          String userId = payload.getSubject();
         logger.info("User ID: " + userId);

          // Get profile information from payload
          String email = payload.getEmail();
          boolean emailVerified = Boolean.valueOf(payload.getEmailVerified());
          String name = (String) payload.get("name");
          String pictureUrl = (String) payload.get("picture");
          String locale = (String) payload.get("locale");
          String familyName = (String) payload.get("family_name");
          String givenName = (String) payload.get("given_name");

            logger.info(email+":"+name+":"+pictureUrl+":"+familyName+":"+givenName);
          // Use or store profile information
          // ...

        } else {
          System.out.println("Invalid ID token.");
```

Answer (score 0):

use  : .setIssuer("accounts.google.com") instead of setIssuer("https://accounts.google.com")